# Can I define/piece together a javascript class within golang?

Tags: javascript, class, go, webassembly

I have experience in Go but am totally green when it comes to Javascript. I've started playing around with Go's js/wasm target. I was wondering whether it's possible to define a JS class within golang. The `syscall/js` package provides no direct way to do so, but according to [a tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), a JS class is essentially just a constructor function and a prototype. So I attempted to build the `Rectangle` toy example from the tutorial in Go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "syscall/js"
)

// Attempt to create a simple javascript class:
//
// class Rectangle {
//   constructor(height, width) {
//     this.height = height;
//     this.width = width;
//   }
//
//   // Method
//   area() {
//     return this.height * this.width;
//   }
// }

func rectangleArea(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    height := this.Get("height").Float()
    width := this.Get("width").Float()
    return height * width
}

func rectangleConstructor(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
    this.Set("height", args[0])
    this.Set("width", args[1])
    return this
}

func main() {
    const name = "Rectangle"
    rectangle := js.FuncOf(rectangleConstructor)
    rectangle.Set("prototype", map[string]interface{}{
        "constructor": rectangle,
        "area":        js.FuncOf(rectangleArea),
    })
    js.Global().Set(name, rectangle)
    select {}
}
```

It *seems* to work in my browser's Javascript console: I can instantiate a `Rectangle`, extend the class, and so on. Cool. The one thing that worries me is that direct comparison between my `Rectangle` class and an identical `Rectangle2` class defined in the JS console yields differences:

```
> Rectangle
function _makeFuncWrapper()
​  length: 0
​  name: ""
​  prototype: Object { constructor: _makeFuncWrapper(), area: _makeFuncWrapper() }
​​    area: function _makeFuncWrapper()​​
    constructor: function _makeFuncWrapper()​​
    <prototype>: Object { … }
​  <prototype>: function ()

> Rectangle2
class Rectangle2 { constructor(height, width) }
  length: 2
  name: "Rectangle2"
  prototype: Object { … }
    area: function area()
    constructor: class Rectangle2 { constructor(height, width) }
    <prototype>: Object { … }
  <prototype>: function ()
```

Of course, the differences might all be due to special Go/wasm magic.

Long story short, my question is: **Is what I'm doing a sound and sane way to define JS classes from within Go? If not, is there a better way?**

Comment: "Of course, the differences might all be due to special Go/wasm magic" AFAICT, pretty much.

Answer (score -1):

Browser-specific stuff, like creating a  tag with a class inside, you'll do like the code below, interacting with the browser.

However, things that are not browser specific, continue in go native.

```
//go:build js

package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "syscall/js"
)

//native go code
type Retangle struct {
    width  int64
    height int64
}

func (r *Retangle) Init(width, height int64) {
    r.width = width
    r.height = height
}

func (r Retangle) Area() int64 {
    return r.width * r.height
}

func main() {
    var class = //"<![CDATA[\n"+
    "div {\n" +
    "color: red;\n" +
    "}\n"
    //"]]>",
    
    rect := Retangle{}
    rect.Init(10, 20)
    
    //browser js code
    var tagStyle js.Value
    tagStyle = js.Global().Get("document").Call("createElement", "style")
    tagStyle.Set("innerHTML", class)
    
    js.Global().Get("document").Get("body").Call("appendChild", tagStyle)
    
    var tagDiv js.Value
    tagDiv = js.Global().Get("document").Call("createElement", "div")
    tagDiv.Set("innerHTML", "área: "+strconv.FormatInt(rect.Area(), 10))
    
    js.Global().Get("document").Get("body").Call("appendChild", tagDiv)
}
```

Can you understand when to use one and the other?

Makefile:

```
GO ?= go

.PHONY: help
## this help command
help:
    @printf "Opções de comandos\n\n"
    @awk '/^[a-zA-Z\-\_0-9]+:/ { \
        helpMessage = match(lastLine, /^## (.*)/); \
        if (helpMessage) { \
            helpCommand = substr($$1, 0, index($$1, ":")-1); \
            helpMessage = substr(lastLine, RSTART + 3, RLENGTH); \
            printf "make %-30s ## %s\n", helpCommand, helpMessage; \
        } \
    } \
    { lastLine = $$0 }' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

.PHONY: build
## build this example
build:
    $(GO) mod tidy
    GOARCH=wasm GOOS=js $(GO) build -o main.wasm
```

Html output:

```
<style>
div {
    color: red;
}
</style>
<div>área: 200</div>
```

Comment: My golang version don't have `js.NewCallback()` function...